# iOS8 Xcode6 UIImageView get misplaced

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, ios8, xcode6

I have a UIImageView in my project that I use to play a movie and do some animations. All worked fine in iOS6-7 but in iOS8 the UIImageView get misplaced on iPad. I used springs and struts for autoresizing.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Can you post the code to position this view?

Comment: No code. It is centred with springs and struts.

Answer (score 1):

Use Auto-Layout instead of Springs and struts. It will solve your problem. I've also faced the same problem when i was running my project without Auto-layout.